# The requested resource is not available.

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm making a registration application with JDBC. But I m getting this error. I think I have a problem with my java.bean my fields are empty.

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 version="2.5">
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.pfa.Servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.pfa.Servlets.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/registerServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

User.java

```
package com.pfa.bean;

public class User {

 private String uname,upass,uemail;  

  public String getUname() {  
     return uname;  
  }   

  public void setUname(String uname) {  
     this.uname = uname;  
  }  

  public String getUpass() {  
     return upass;  
  }  

  public void setUpass(String upass) {  
     this.upass = upass;  
  }  

    public String getUemail() {  
     return uemail;  
   }  

   public void setUemail(String uemail) {  
      this.uemail = uemail;  
       }  
 }
```

Register.Dao

```
  package com.pfa.Dao;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
  import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
  import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
  import com.pfa.bean.User;

  public class RegisterDao {
  public static int register(User u) throws ClassNotFoundException{  
    int status=0; 

    try{  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = null;          
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/form",    "root", "");
            Statement ps =  (Statement) conn
                    .createStatement();
            Statement ps1 = (Statement) conn
                    .createStatement();
            ResultSet res = ps
                    .executeQuery("Select * from user");
            // Process the result set
            boolean test = false;
            while (res.next()) {
                if ((res.getString("userName").equals(u.getUname()))
                        || (res.getString("password")
                                .equals(u.getUpass()))||    (res.getString("email").equals(u.getUemail()))) {
                    test = true;
                    status=0;
                     System.out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Y ou ve a  lreadyy Logged in</p>");  
                }
            }

            if (!test) {
                    String query = "insert into user"
                            + " (userName ,password,email)"
                            + " values ('" + u.getUname() + "','"
                            + u.getUpass() + "','" +u.getUemail()+")";

                    ps1.executeUpdate(query);
                    System.out.println("Insert complete");
                status=1;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

      return status;  
        }  
  }
```

RegisterServlet.java

```
 package com.pfa.Servlets;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
 import com.pfa.Dao.LoginDao;
 import com.pfa.Dao.RegisterDao;
 import com.pfa.bean.User;
  public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String n = request.getParameter("username");
       //String p = request.getParameter("userpass");
       //String q = request.getParameter("useremail");
       HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
      if (session != null)
        session.setAttribute("name",n);
      User u = new User();
      try {
        if (RegisterDao.register(u)!=0) {
            RequestDispatcher rd =      request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry u ve already Logged  in</p>");
            RequestDispatcher rd =  request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.close();
    }
 }
```

register.jsp

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
      pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

     <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859- 1">
     <title>Login Application</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form action="Process.jsp" method="post">
      <fieldset style="width: 300px">
         <legend> Register to App </legend>
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <td>User ID</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="username" required="required"                   /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>Password</td>
                 <td><input type="password" name="userpass"  required="required" /></td>

             </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>email</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="useremail" required="required"        /></td>

             <tr>

                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
           </fieldset>
         </form>
       </body>
     </html>
```

process.jsp

```
       <%@page import="com.pfa.Dao.*"%>  
       <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.pfa.bean.User"/>  
        <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>  
     <% 
     int status=RegisterDao.register(obj);  
     if(status>0)  
     out.print("You are successfully registered");    
     %>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text of the error which you're getting.

Comment: where do you get *this error* - when you click on something, or even when you try to load a servlet? Can you provide a Stacktrace?

Comment: actually The stack trace doesn t show me any error!!! And I was sure that the error came from my javabean file coz I made sop and it showed a null value ! Well I chanded my java bean file and the fields are the same as my database But still getting the same error well the structure of my project may it be wrong I have webcontent (WEB-INF(lib-web.xml)/process.jsp/register.jsp)

Comment: And I got this error when I write the name,email and password and click submit to register

Comment: actially this path find it unavailable /SignInProject/Process.jsp !!

Answer (score 0):

username,should use setUsername but not setUname,you can find some resource about the reflect of java,and some recommend for you ,you should better use preparedstatement for looking up the result like "select * from user where uname=’？’"，(to avoid sql injection,and more efficient)

Comment: actually The stack trace doesn t show me any error!!! And I was sure that the error came from my javabean file coz I made sop and it showed a null value ! Well I chanded my java bean file and the fields are the same as my database But still getting the same error well the structure of my project may it be wrong I have webcontent (WEB-INF(lib-web.xml)/process.jsp/register.jsp) And I got this error when I write the name,email and password and click submit to register actially this path find it unavailable /SignInProject/Process.jsp !!